# check of coordinates in a tick does not work (opengl)

Tags: c++, opengl

I wanted to make a snake on opengl.I wanted to make a snake at the opening. But she eats fruit only 2 times. This does not work check in tick and I can not understand why.

This code
(main cpp)

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
GLfloat coord[2] = {0,0};
GLfloat fruitcootd[2] = {0,0};
GLint snakecount;
bool eat = 1;

void rdmfruit()
{
    fruitcootd[0] = 0;
    fruitcootd[1] = 0;
    int s;
    s = rand() % 2;
    if(s == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 1 + rand() % 5;i > 0;i--)
        {
            fruitcootd[0] = fruitcootd[0] - 0.154;
        }
    }
    else if(s > 0)
    {
            for(int i = 1 + rand() % 5;i > 0;i--)
        {
            fruitcootd[0] = fruitcootd[0] + 0.154;
        }
    }
    s = rand() % 2;
    if(s == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 2 + rand() % 5;i > 0;i--)
        {
            fruitcootd[1] = fruitcootd[1] - 0.154;
        }
    }
    else if(s > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 2 + rand() % 5;i > 0;i--)
        {
            fruitcootd[1] = fruitcootd[1] + 0.154;
        }
    }
}

void DrawMap()
{
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for(float i = -1; i < 1;i = i + 0.154)
    {
        glVertex2f(i, 1);
        glVertex2f(i, -1);
    }
    for(float i = -1; i < 1;i = i + 0.154)
    {
        glVertex2f(-1, i);
        glVertex2f(1, i);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void snake()
{
      glPointSize(30);
      glColor3d(1,0,1);
      glBegin(GL_POINTS);
      glVertex2f(coord[0],coord[1]);
      glEnd();
}

void fruit()
{

    glPointSize(20);
    glColor3d(0,1,0);
    if(eat)
    {
    fruitcootd[0] = 0;
    fruitcootd[1] = 0;
            rdmfruit();
            eat = 0;
    }
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(fruitcootd[0],fruitcootd[1]);
    glEnd();
}


void init()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDepthRange(100,100);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    DrawMap();
    fruit();
    snake();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void tick(int)
{
    if(coord[0] == fruitcootd[0] && coord[1] == fruitcootd[1] && !eat)
    {
        cout<<1<<endl;
        eat = 1;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1,tick,0);
}

void key(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case 'w':
        coord[1] = coord[1] + 0.154;
        break;
            case 'a':
        coord[0] = coord[0] - 0.154;
        break;
            case 's':
        coord[1] = coord[1] - 0.154;
        break;
            case 'd':
        coord[0] = coord[0] + 0.154;
        break;
            case 'h':
                eat = 1;
                cout<<"------------"<<endl;
                cout<<"FruitX:"<<fruitcootd[0]<<endl;
                cout<<"FruitY:"<<fruitcootd[1]<<endl;
                break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,640);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutCreateWindow("Snake");


    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);
    glutTimerFunc(1,tick,0);

    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please read up on how to create a [mcve] and post it in your question (*not* as a off-site link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an floating point precision issue in your code. When 2 floating point values are tested for equality, then an epsilon should be used:

e.g. A == B should be done like

```
fabs(A-B) < espi
```

where `A` and `B` are floating point numbers and `espi` is a very small value.

Change your code like this:

```
void tick(int)
{
   const double epsi = 0.0001;
   if (fabs(coord[0]-fruitcootd[0]) < epsi &&
       fabs(coord[1]-fruitcootd[1]) < epsi &&
       !eat )
    {
        cout<<1<<endl;
        eat = 1;
    }

    .....
}
```